# Cookie и iframe

Tags: php, cookie

Только что узнал, что cookie не работают в iframe. Например, **если сайт открыт в iframe** и задаются куки, то они просто не задаются.

```
setCookie('test', 123, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, '/');
```

Возможно ли как-то задать cookie, если сайт в iframe? Ответы при помощи известных поисковиков не помогли, всё не работает.

Comment: iframe - по сути открыть другой сайт у себя. Кукисы ты задаешь для текущей страницы, которая содержит iframe. По идеи, ты никак не можешь это сделать. Если я правильно понял, то надо куки использовать в iframe?

Comment: @mepihindeveloper, Вы всё верно поняли. Но как я понял это невозможно.